# OSX seems to be ignoring any DYLD_* environment variables

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I'm attempting to use a 3rd party SDK which is primarily written in C++. Their recommended approach for running the compiled output (an ODBC driver) on OSX includes setting an environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain paths to some required libraries.

Setting this variable worked fine for testing the driver via command line utilities, but for GUI applications launched outside of the current shell session I'd need `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set globally.

After following some of the Yosemite specific instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite I was able to set toy variables system wide, e.g.: `launchctl setenv FOO BAR` and have those show up after reboot, but any variable starting with the substring `DYLD` would be absent from my environment.

I've since resolved the problem by compiling the project with static libraries included explicitly, but the question remains:

Why are variables starting specifically with `"DYLD"` being ignored?

Comment: AFAIK, something to do with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4143805?tstart=0) seems to indicate that there have been problems for a bit longer than.